# Mapping Multiple Controllers in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Define two controllers user and data as follows:

```
// 1st Controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "user"})
public class UserLoginController {
  @Autowired
    private UserLoginService userLoginService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm(@ModelAttribute UserLogin userLogin) {
        //model.addAttribute(new UserLogin());
        //System.out.println("showLoginForm() is called");

        return "loginForm";
    }   

}

    //Second COntroller

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "user/data/")
public class WorkplanController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkplanService WorkplanService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "importForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView importForm(@ModelAttribute SheetUpload sheetUpload){
        return new ModelAndView("uploadWorkplan");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doUpload(@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] uploadFile, SheetUpload fileUpload, Workplan workplan, HttpServletRequest request) {
return new ModelAndView("uploadSucess");
   }

}
```

When i make request to the doUpload(), it shows  HTTP Status 400 Error.
My question is two-fold:
1. Why do have i have to include the user like this: @RequestMapping(value = "user/data/") to make request to the 2nd controller why not like this @RequestMapping(value = "data/")?
2. What do i need to change to make a successful call to the 2nd method in the second controller?

Here is the form am trying to submit:

```
<form:form action="doUpload"  modelAttribute="sheetUpload" method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <form:select class="createusers_select_menu" path="From">
      <form:option value="">Select...</form:option>
      <form:option value="A">A</form:option>
      <form:option value="B">B</form:option>
      <form:option value="C">C</form:option>
   </form:select>
   <form:input class="browse_btn" path="uploadFile" type="file" />
   <input type="submit" class="selct_workplan_2_btn" name=""  value=" "/>  
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do have i have to include the user like this: @RequestMapping(value = "user/data/") to make request to the 2nd controller why not like this @RequestMapping(value = "data/")?

You don't have to. Change it to `@RequestMapping(value="/data")`

> What do i need to change to make a successful call to the 2nd method in the second controller?

Try to get it working with a single file field only, then report back. There are lots of tutorials on the web to show how to upload files with Spring.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. i had changed and worked. i guess my netbeans IDE was caching bcos previously it didnt work. And yes i only needed to solve that issue. its clear what do next now